# How to restrict DynamoDB createTable using an IAM Role?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-iam

I'm trying to limit access to an IAM role that I have. Instead of assigning  `AmazonDynamoDBFullAccess` policy to it. I want to specifically allow access to the tables the role needs (CRUD).

Additionally, the role needs to be able to create tables conditionally based on a string comparison that uses a wild card like so: `*_user_table`.

So, the IAM role can only access certain tables, and can only create tables that have the _user_table suffix.

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm assuming you want to restrict the actions your IAM Role can perform on DynamoDB. You can achieve this by creating a policy and attaching it to your role, with a statement for describing the tables and another one for the CRUD operations and creation of tables.

The key point here, is the usage of the wildcard in the resources (ARNs) list:

```json
"Resource": "arn:aws:dynamodb:*:*:table/*_user_table"
```

Below is an example as seen in the documentation:

```json
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "ListAndDescribe",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "dynamodb:List*",
                "dynamodb:DescribeReservedCapacity*",
                "dynamodb:DescribeLimits",
                "dynamodb:DescribeTimeToLive"
            ],
            "Resource": "*"
        },
        {
            "Sid": "SpecificTable",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "dynamodb:BatchGet*",
                "dynamodb:DescribeStream",
                "dynamodb:DescribeTable",
                "dynamodb:Get*",
                "dynamodb:Query",
                "dynamodb:Scan",
                "dynamodb:BatchWrite*",
                "dynamodb:CreateTable",
                "dynamodb:Delete*",
                "dynamodb:Update*",
                "dynamodb:PutItem"
            ],
            "Resource": "arn:aws:dynamodb:*:*:table/*_user_table"
        }
    ]
}
```

Here's some useful references in the documentation.

- [Amazon DynamoDB: Allows access to a specific table](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/reference_policies_examples_dynamodb_specific-table.html)
- [Policies and permissions in IAM](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/access_policies.html)
- [Some considerations on the DynamoDB arn format](https://rockset.com/docs/amazon-dynamodb/)

I edited your question for clarity.

Comment: Suspect you meant `*_user_table` rather than `* _user_table` (with a space).

Comment: That's correct. I was problably typing too fast. It's fixed, thank you.